# Comparing elements in a nested list by a condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a nested list which contains two elements in each nested list, the second element being the one that is condition.

```
lst = [[2, 1], [5, 1], [10, 1], [9, 1], [10, 2], [18, 2]]
```

If a first index in a sub list is less than the first index in the subsequent list for all 1's in the list (second sub-list element), the counter value should increment by one. Similarly, for all 2's in the list. For instance, the counter is set to 1. For all 1's in the list: 2 < 5, 5 < 10 - the counter stays at 1. However, in the next comparison 10 < 9 is false, so the counter increments by 1. The program should then print 2. Now for all 2's in the list, 10 < 18, so the counter variable just prints 1. Therefore program prints 2 1 as its output.

I'm a bit stuck as to how to implement this. So I started thinking about it step by step. It would make sense to have a for loop that compares each first index. So what I did was append each first sub list element to a new list.

```
count = 1
newlst = []
for item in lst:
    newlst.append(item[0])
```

The list looks like this:

```
[2, 5, 10, 9, 10, 18]
```

But, if even if I compare all these values, i.e checking if the index < index + 1. It wouldn't output 2 1. More than likely, it would just output 1. And how can it be compared on this basis of the second sub list element, for all the 1's and then 2's? Is there another way to do this so that the program can output 2 1?

NB: The input of the list is not necessarily this list, it could be any nested list with 2 elements in each sub list, i.e. [[4, 1], [8, 1], [1, 2], [6, 2], [15, 3], [9, 3]] - output of this would be 1 1 2.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.
This question boils down to "I can't figure out how to do my homework", which is too broad for Stack Overflow.  This suggests that you need to walk through the applicable class exercises again, use an on-line tutorial, or spend half an hour with a local tutor.

Comment: @Prune I am familiar with the rules, it's just that I have been on this problem for the past 3 days, so asking for help on this site was the very last resort.

Comment: Your description of the algorithm is clear enough, but you haven't shown an attempt to code those steps.  Instead, you *removed* the necessary class labels (second element of each pair), and then pointed out that there is no longer sufficient information to solve the problem.  Take the steps in that nice description and code *that*, one step at a time.  Use `print` statements to trace your work at each step.

Comment: @Prune okay, noted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After clarifying the question I have to refer to @Robᵩ, who almost nailed it.

```
from itertools import groupby
lst = lst=[[4, 1], [8, 1], [1, 2], [6, 2], [15, 3], [9, 3]]
    for __,grp in groupby(lst, key=lambda x:x[1]):
    grp = list(grp)
    print (sum((i<j) for i,j in zip(grp[1:],grp))+1)
```

Only thing that had to be changed is the order of the two lists in zip() and also adding  `+1` as the counter should start with one.

Now this should print your desired output.

Comment: I entered this with the other list [[4, 1], [8, 1], [1, 2], [6, 2], [15, 3], [9, 3]] , and I got 3 1 as the result. When it should have been 1 1 2.

Comment: Why do you expect the Output to be three numbers, if the number of values in the sublist is 2? 
As far as I understood, you want a sum of (i>i+1), and the counter starting with 1.
Please clarify

Comment: According to this logic the first list is `[4, 8, 1, 6, 15, 9]`
So we have 8>1, and 15>9. Value of the counter should be 2+1=3.

Second list is `[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]`. Since there is no value that fulfills your condition the counter stays at 1.

Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: There's just a slight misunderstanding. The 8 (from the 1 sub-list) shouldn't be compared to the 1 (from the 2 sub-list) because the 1 has the second element 2 in its sub-list. For example, for the sub-lists with the elements 1:    [4,1], [8,1]. Since 4 < 8, the counter stays at 1, and then prints 1. It then proceeds to the sub lists with 2's in them i.e.  [1,2], [6,2]. This also would print 1 because 1 < 6. On the other hand, for the sub lists with 3 as their second element, since 15 < 9 is false, the counter increments by 1, thus producing 2. Hence, why the final output would be: 1 1 2.

Comment: Got it now, thanks for clarification. Changed the code, have a look.

Answer (score 0):

This program gets the `2 1` from your first dataset:

```
from itertools import groupby

lst = [[2, 1], [5, 1], [10, 1], [9, 1], [10, 2], [18, 2]]

for _, grp in groupby(lst, key=lambda x:x[1]):
    grp = list(grp)
    print (sum((i<j) for i,j in zip(grp, grp[1:])))
```